# How to change background color of the selected item in a list

Tags: jquery, html-lists

How do I change the background color of the selected item in a list.
I'm not sure whether this is done in the CSS or my script.

```
<script id="INLINE_PEN_JS_ID">
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();

  $('.accordion-list > li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                                      
       if (event.target.closest('a')) {
        // an <a> was clicked
        return;
        }   
      $(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
      
    } else {
        
      $(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      $(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
      $(".accordion-list > li.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    return false;
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest you change it in both, in a sense. Use CSS to assign the background color via a Class. Then you can add / remove the Class with jQuery as desired. That way if you feel you want to change the color, you only have to update the CSS once.

Comment: I do not see where `event` is defined in your script. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is a syntax error in this line: `$(".accordion-list > li.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: `.style` is a DOM property. If you're using jQuery you use the `.css()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();
  $('.accordion-list > li').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      if ($("a", this).length && $(event.target).is("a")) {
        // <LI> contains <A> && <A> was clicked
        return;
      }
      $(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
    } else {
      $(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      $(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-list>li {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.accordion-list>li.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="accordion-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li class="active"><i class="answer"></i>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

As you did not provide an example, I had to make some guesses. You can see that this is using both CSS and jQuery to help highlight the targeted list item.

> The `closest()` method traverses the Element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns `null`.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest